# How to pass user's id in DeleteConfirmed action in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The code looks as following:

1) Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return PartialView(user);
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        // Remove all the User Group references:
        await this.GroupManager.ClearUserGroupsAsync(id);

        // Then Delete the User:
        var result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
            return PartialView();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return PartialView();
}
```

2) Delete view:

```
@model StatusZN.Models.ApplicationUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete.</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this User?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>User.</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dd>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
        </dd>
    </dl>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "UsersAdmin", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "UsersDiv"}, new { id = Model.Id}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
            <a href="#" onclick="BackToUsersList()">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Visualy it looks as following:

[image]

The issue is the program flow enters DeleteConfirmed action, but argument id is null.

How to pass argument, which exists in model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using the wrong overload of `Ajax.BeginForm()` and are adding `length=10` as a route value (because `"UsersAdmin"` has 10 characters) and `adding` the `id` as a html attribute to your `<form>` tag. You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions%29), so its

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", "UsersAdmin", new { id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { ....} ))
```

where the 3rd parameter is the `routeValues`